# Magento Connect missing in System Dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect

for some reason our Magento Connect menu item is not appearing under the System dropdown in the admin panel.

I have made sure that it is enabled in the advanced section in conficuration, but still don't see it. Is there anot

Comment: Are you one of the lucky people on a properly managed server with a staging server? Magento Connect was found to be a liability in a former life and has been removed/disabled from the live system and protections put in place so can't be used to corrupt the staging server.

Answer (score 1):

you may have an extension that have rewritten your extension, try to disable extensions that you have installed recently one by one and clear the cache to see if it appears again then when you figured out the module go to xml files of that module adminhtml.xml and config.xml

also,what do you see in this path?

```
 app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\etc\adminhtml.xml
```

you should have something similar to

```
<extensions translate="title">
                            <title>Magento Connect</title>
                            <children>
                                <local translate="title">
                                    <title>Magento Connect Manager</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </local>
                                <custom translate="title">
                                    <title>Package Extensions</title>
                                    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                                </custom>
                            </children>
                        </extensions>
```

It can also be corrupted theme xml files, it depends on your changes, so I suggest you go ahead and try to figure out xml layout files.
try to uninstall the suspicious extension and also do not forget to clear your cache